# Apache beam python get distinct values from list of dictionary

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have list of dictionary in dataflow. I have converted the columns into dictionary of key value pair. Now I want to get distinct values of each column. How can i do this in dataflow without sending the entire data as side input. I can achieve this as a side input data.

Answer (score 0):

you may create a combiner for a groupbykey operation that counts the occurrences of a key. In that way you'll get a list of couples (key, count). This is feasible as long as you have only few keys to check, IMHO.